# Что такое jar файл и зачем он нужен?

Tags: java, jar

Вопрос такой что такое **jar** файл и зачем он нужен на практике. Ведь если есть файл **java**, есть файл **class** который уже переведен в байт-код, зачем тогда **jar** файл?

Какая его функция и можно ли без него обойтись?

Comment: А если в вашем приложении 200 классов?

Comment: Это аналог EXE.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**JAR-файл** — это Java-архив (**J**ava **AR**chive). Это простой архивный файл, сжатый (иногда с нулевой компрессией) по алгоритму **zip**.

Он был создан для удобства распространения программ, написанных на **Java**. Так как обычная программа содержит сотни, тысячи, а иногда и миллионы файлов. Файл может содержать:

- файл манифеста `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`
- **java-файлы** (исходный код)
- **class-файлы**
- файлы, необходимые для работы программы: картинки, файлы с настройками и прочее (ресурсы)
- электронные подписи, которые позволяют защитить программу от модификации

**Манифест** - это текстовый файл формата `ключ: значение`; он содержит описание **jar-файла**. В нем могут быть следующие ключи:

- **Manifest-Version** - версия манифеста
- **Main-Class** - имя главного класса (должен содержать метод `main`), такой **jar-файл** можно запустить как обычный исполняемый файл
- **Class-Path** - позволяет указать `CLASSPATH`, который необходим для полноценной работы программы
- **SHA-Digest** - контрольная сумма определенного файла внутри архива

Кроме **jar**, также существуют другие архивы, связанные с Java:

- **WAR** (**W**eb **A**pplication a**R**chive) - содержит в себе приложение для веба
- **EAR** (**E**nterprise **A**pplication a**R**chive) - содержит в себе энтерпрайз приложение (обычно из нескольких модулей)
- **APK** (**A**ndroid a**P**plication pac**K**age) - содержит в себе приложение для Android

**Можно ли обойтись без?**

В принципе, можно, все что вам необходимо - это **всегда** точно копировать структуру вашего приложения. То есть все класс-файлы и файлы с ресурсами должны располагаться в правильных директориях. Переменная **CLASSPATH** должна содержать пути ко всем зависимостям. Если эти условия соблюдены, то ваше приложение будет работать без упаковки в **jar**.

***P.S.*** В переводе с английского, **jar** - означает **банка**, стеклянный или керамический цилиндрический контейнер с широким горлом, предназначенный для хранения еды (обычно). Кофе часто хранят в банках, так что тут игра слов: банка с кофе - банка с java-классами.

Comment: Нелишне будет добавить, что *JAR* означает по английски *банка*, так что это не просто *Java ARchive*, но для носителя языка еще и имеет подтекст *банка заполненная классами*

Comment: @Barmaley верное замечание. добавил.

Comment: я догадываюсь но задаю вопрос можно ли обойтись без jar файла и как

Comment: я догадываюсь но задаю вопрос можно ли обойтись без jar файла и как   и как часто используют jar файл в различных проектах и процессе обучения

Comment: @ВиталийVit, без них не обойтись. Ну, т.е. можно обходиться, но вам точно не захочется. Т.е. может и захочется, но только ради спортивного интереса. В `jar` файлах всякие библиотеки распространяются, а они очень облегчают жизнь. Например подключил файл к проекту и можно `JSON` парсить просто и удобно. А самому, вручную делать это - боль. Так что ответ - используют все и всегда, без них не обойтись.

Comment: @ВиталийVit обновил ответ.